# How can I return a boolean through a class using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

thanks for your time first of all.
NetBeans is not showing me any problem, I basically want to check if an username exists in the database. If that happens, continue on creating new class (as in classroom ) into the database. 
I have an if else statement, which checks wether or not the username is in the database, and even though it is, I cannot get it to work.

I have the feeling the problem is in CheckUsernameExists.java.

Maybe someone can give me a hint on what is the problem.

Thanks a lot for your time

AdminClassesPanelController.java:

```
else if(event.getSource() == create_class_button){
            CheckUsernameExists checkUser = new CheckUsernameExists(new_class_add_student_field.getText(),1);
            //checkUser.CheckUsernameExists(new_class_add_student_field.getText(),1);
            boolean usernameExists = checkUser.GetStudentExists();
           if(usernameExists == true){
               try
        { 
            //Variables: //////
           String teacherProfit = new_class_teacher_profit_field.getText();
           int teacherProfitInt = Integer.parseInt(teacherProfit);
           String numberOfClasses = new_class_class_count_field.getText();
           int numberOfClassesInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfClasses);

           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gtc?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");

           Statement st = conn.createStatement();
           st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CLASS(id,language,teachersalary,classnumber,studentidforclass,teacheridforclass) VALUES ('"+new_class_id_field.getText()+"','"+create_class_combo_box.getValue()+"','"+teacherProfitInt+"','"+numberOfClassesInt+"','"+new_class_add_student_field.getText()+"','"+new_class_add_teacher_field+"')");
           System.out.println("Clase creada correctamente.");
           class_text.setText("Clase creada correctamente");


            conn.close();

        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Connection with Database failed");
            System.err.println(e); 
        }  
    }

       else {
           class_text.setText("The introduced student ID cant be found in the Database.");
       }   

    }

}
```

CheckUsernameExists.java:

```
public class CheckUsernameExists {

boolean usernameExists = false;
String usernameCounter;

//teacherOrStudent == 1 -> Student ---------------- teacherOrStudent == 2 -> Teacher
public CheckUsernameExists(String username, int teacherOrStudent){

    if (teacherOrStudent == 1){
        try
    { 

       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gtc?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");

       Statement stCheckUsers = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rsCheckUsers = stCheckUsers.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENT");
       if(rsCheckUsers.next()) 
     {
       usernameCounter = rsCheckUsers.getString("id");
       if(usernameCounter.equals(username))
       {
           System.out.println("It already exists");
          usernameExists = true;

       }


     }


        conn.close();

    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Connection with Database failed");
        System.err.println(e); 
    }  




    }
//        return usernameExists;
} 
        public boolean GetStudentExists(){
            return this.usernameExists;

        }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Are you sure the `id` column in the STUDENT table holds a username?  What other columns does that table have?

Comment: Hi @VGR, the columns are: "id", "pwd", "fullname".

Comment: Your code only checks the first line in the db table.If you want to do this like that,you should restrict the rows to those matching the criterion using the WHERE clause:`PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE id=?");ps.setString(1,username);ResultSet rsCheckUsers=ps.executeQuery();` This you do not need to check the id again since the DB already did this. If there's a UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY constraint on the column,you could simply try to insert the row and handle a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException as existing key.This would also make the operation atomic

Comment: If I look at your `CheckUserNameExists` class I don't think it is doing anything useful. For example, the `SQL` query doesn't search for the right data. I'd advise you to apply Test Driven Development and write a test that asserts your desired behaviour before you continue. Also, please stick to Java naming conventions and code guidelines. Makes it much easier to read.